# getting error as pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "mmc printmanagement.msc"

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to open `printmanagement.msc` using the below code. But getting error.

My code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
Application().start(r'mmc printmanagement.msc')
```

Error:

```
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "mmc printmanagement.msc"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (740, 'CreateProcess', 'The requested operation requires elevation.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elevation means "running as Administrator". You should start Python process as Administrator (or your IDE, or cmd.exe before starting python.exe in a console). The parent process for `mmc.exe` must run as Administrator.

Another way to allow automatic elevation (if Python is not a privileged process):

```
Application().start(r'cmd.exe /c mmc.exe printmanagement.msc', wait_for_idle=False)
```

And then you need to connect to child `mmc.exe` process this way.

```
app = Application(backend='win32').connect(path='mmc.exe')
# or using backend="uia" whatever is better
```

Because launcher process `cmd.exe` exits immediately. pywinauto can't detect and handle spawned child processes automatically but we have such feature request.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, Now I can able to launch to printmanagement.msc . But getting this error now, pywinauto.application.ProcessNotFoundError: Process "mmc.exe" not found!.            How to resolve this?

Comment: More info: when connecting to child process using app = Application(backend='win32').connect(path='mmc.exe'), getting error-pywinauto.application.ProcessNotFoundError: Process "mmc.exe" not found!

Comment: This is because mmc.exe performs self-elevation. So running Python as Administrator is a must. By the way. if the answer is correct and it solves your problem, please mark it as accepted (click gray check box at the left side of answer). It saves time for others (not reading solved problems) and motivates all for future answers.